# Release Update for unreleased App in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an approved App in iTunes Connect which is not yet released (release date set to December 20th).

I decided to change a few things so I submitted an update, now this update has been approved as well and is "Pending Developer Release".

If I release the update now will the app become visible on the App Store, even though the release date under "rights and pricing" is set to December 20th?

Comment: Reject the bundle and submit the update.  Either way, you'll be subject to a re-review.

Comment: @CodaFi I think the update has also been approved

Comment: Nothing can be rejected...both are approved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't go live until the 20th December. 'Pending Developer Release' is just a staging area until you approve that it's OK to override the original release.

Comment: Have you experienced this first hand? Would be a shame if it went live the second I "release" the update

Comment: Worse case scenario, you can go in to Rights and Pricing and change the date again. But yes, I've used this before and my app didn't immediately go live, but the master version changed to my latest update.

Comment: I just took a chance and did it, seems to have worked. Thank you for the fast answer!

Comment: I just did the same, the app was not released immediately, but on the date I specified. so, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Do they both have the same bundle name?
If so, can you delete the first one and only have the second one that you want anyways?